# Why can't I make a .exe with anything using pandas anymore?

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, executable, cx-freeze

So, I used to use auto-py-to-exe to create exe files.  This worked great a week ago.  I created a few scripts that used pandas and some other libraries.  Now when I try to make something and double click the file it just opens cmd and then shuts down immediately.  I even just tried making a simple hello world script that just imported pandas, printed hello, then asked for an input to pause the program.  If I do that without importing pandas, the .exe works fine.  If I put import pandas into the script, then the .exe will fail.

Nothing fails when I run it through spyder or anything.  It just fails when I put make it an executable file.

I have uninstalled auto-py-to-exe and reinstalled it.  Uninstalled pyinstaller and reinstalled.  I tried completely uninstalling anaconda and libraries and reinstalling.  I tried using cx_Freeze.  All have the same results.

I tried using the advice here [build python script to single exe with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753373/build-python-script-to-single-exe-with-pyinstaller).  Same result.

Anyone have a solution to this?  I don't know why it is suddenly not working.

Also, I am a pretty noob developer here, so I imagine I am just messing something simple up, but I can't figure it out.

example of my simple script:

```
import pandas as pd
print('hello world')
pause = input('hit enter to end')
```

also if I run the program in cmd I get this error -

INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Comment: Does import `pandas` raise an exception?

Comment: not in Spyder.  It just seems to break when I make it an exe.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that pyinstaller wasn't finding my libraries.  The solution was to create a virtual environment and launch from there.  I used this setup as a guide.  https://medium.com/@liron92/pyinstaller-with-pandas-problems-solutions-and-workflow-with-code-examples-c72973e1e23f   Basically just create a virtual environment, pip install all the libraries you need, then launch auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller from that environment.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should install pandas on terminal please use pip install pandas. After installing pandas try again and it will work.