# Color an entire DataFrame based on distinct values in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

This question is a continuation to my previously asked question
([Color a Pandas DataFrame column based on distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347182/color-a-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-distinct-values))

So basically, i want to highlight the entire rows of a DataFrame, based on the distinct values in a particular column (In this case, its the "Country" column)

Here is how i am trying to achieve this

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Country":['xx','xx','xy','xz','xz'],
               "year":['y1','y2','y1','y1','y2'],
               "population":[100,200,120,140,190]})


import matplotlib

colors = dict(zip(d1['Country'].unique(),
              (f'background-color: {c}' for c in matplotlib.colors.cnames.values())))


def test_check(df):
    for key in colors:
        # print(key)
        if key in df['Country']:
            return colors.get(key)
        else:
            pass
        
    
d2 = d1.style.apply(test_check, axis=1)
```

but i end up with this error

> ValueError: Function <function test_check at 0x0000024D090E98B0> returned the wrong shape.
> Result has shape: (5,)
> Expected shape:   (5, 3)

I want my output to be something like this. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says, it expects (5,3) here there are 5 rows and 3 columns but it only gets 5 elements. It is expecting color for each column in a row which causes the error.

If you follow something like the [other answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747371/5916727), I think it should work. All you need is `pd.Series(colors[row['Country']], row.index)` in your `test_check` function. You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Country":['xx','xx','xy','xz','xz'],
               "year":['y1','y2','y1','y1','y2'],
               "population":[100,200,120,140,190]})



colors = dict(zip(d1['Country'].unique(),
              (f'background-color: {c}' for c in matplotlib.colors.cnames.values())))


def test_check(row):
    
    return pd.Series(colors[row['Country']], row.index)
    
d1.style.apply(test_check, axis=1)
```

Adding more explanation:

If you try `colors[d1.iloc[0]['Country']]` i.e. colors[row['Country']] where row is first row in the dataframe it returns value from dictionary something like: `'background-color: #F0F8FF'`
And passing `test_check(d1.iloc[0])` it returns same color for all three columns of the row i.e. as below for first row:

```
Country       background-color: #F0F8FF
year          background-color: #F0F8FF
population    background-color: #F0F8FF
```

That way for each row gets same color value for the three columns which is applied via Style. You can see what values are returned by `d1.apply(test_check, axis=1)`

Comment: Even though it works ,i do not understand what's happening here. What does colors[row['Country']] return?

Comment: I added few explanation, you can try running and see it is returning 3 values i.e. color  for each column (3 here) instead of 1 which was causing error.